# WCF Service - HTTP Request and Response

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, http, service

I have 2 WCF services:
1. Inbound  - the client calls this service.
2. Outbound - we send information to client.

We now know that the response from client will be in default http response for outbound, and they want us to send a default http response for inbound.

Right now, I have specified the response object as a class. How do I implement http response?, how can I manage my services to send a http response?.

I have tried to search around but I am not getting any starter links for this.
Could you please guide me in the right direction?

What should my response object look like in this case?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking. A service does not send requests, unless it is configured with a duplex binding. What do you mean by _"response from client will be in default http response for outbound"_ and _"send a default http response for inbound"_? What does _"implement http response"_ mean? Why do you want to send an HTTP response?

Comment: I want to know how to handle a default http response and send a default http response. What should my return type look like?

Comment: It is the requirement from client that they need a simple HTTP response like 'Yes' or  'No'    1. response from client will be in default http response for outbound : What I mean by this is: when I call my client's service like this: clientservice.AddThis() what should I bind this object to if the response type is default http response?

Comment: Then WCF might not be the right choice. Take a look at WebAPI.

Comment: So you want your client to send your service a SOAP request and you want your service to respond with "Yes"?

Comment: Yes, thats correct. I want the "Yes" to be in the format of default http response. I want to know how to implement that?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue with this:

To set the response object with the value:

```
WebOperationContext ctx         = WebOperationContext.Current;
ctx.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
```

To retrieve the value I used this:

```
int    statuscode  = HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode;
string description = HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusDescription;
```